# Process hung, wait chain says "One or more threads waiting to finish network I/O"

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg

I have an ffmpeg process that is running, and then all of the sudden the output file stops growing, and the process just sits there with the file locked indefinitely.  If I kill the process, the file ends up being corrupt due to MP4.  If I disconnect wifi, the file ends up being corrupt.  If I disable the network adapter in Windows, ffmpeg is able to gracefully exit.  Strange behavior indeed.  In task manager, I analyzed the wait chain of the process, and it says "One or more threads of ffmpeg.exe are waiting to finish network I/O."

[image: Screenshot of Analyze wait chain]

My question is, what is causing the process to randomly get stuck?

Comment: Not enough info here for us to try it ourselves, so not possible to answer.